# I want to add Share to Slack feature in my web app. Facing issue in showing the popup to select the receipients

Tags: share, slack, slack-dialog, web-share

I am adding share to slack functionality in my web app.
But I cannot find any solution by which I can show my app users to select a user/channel or team in slack to share the content with.

I have added Sharing on Teams also. In that I am able to select the users or search the particular user. Please refer the below link to see how it is looking in teams.
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/power-bi/collaborate-share/media/service-share-report-teams/service-teams-share-to-teams-dialog.png

I want to know, is there any way by which we can implement the sharing to particular user or channel etc on slack same as it is there in teams.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Once the Web app shares content, it's very much up to the receiving app to decide what it makes of the incoming data.

```js
try {
  await navigator.share({
    title: 'Title',
    text: 'Text',
    url: 'https://example.com/',
  });
  console.log('Successful share'))
} catch (err) {
  console.log('Error sharing', err));
}
```

Possible values are:

- `url`: A string representing a URL to be shared.
- `text`: A string representing text to be shared.
- `title`: A string representing a title to be shared. **May be ignored by the target.**

See the bold part. Try populating `text` and `title` differently and see if it makes any difference.